# MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone

I am using mgtwitterEngine to integrate twitter functionality.In my application i want response in XML format so i have done all the changes as metion in readme of mgtwiiter 
for example i have done

```
#define YAJL_AVAILABLE 0
```

in MGTwitterEngineGlobalHeader.h and

```
#define USE_LIBXML 1
```

in MGTwitterEngine.m file and i am checking that API_FORMAT is xml too but whenever i am getting response i am getting in json format.
Please can any one tell me what am i missing? any help would be appreciated.

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at NSLog output for received objects? NSLog output for objects like dictionary or array is similar to JSON format.

Comment: Hi Thanks Donal for reply and i got it but i am getting confuse as how to get value from libparser for example i want to get screen name after updating my status can any one help me how to get it.
As when i went through mgtwitterengine i saw it send NSArray * to statusesReceived method.